# Does conky work with Mir?

Tags: conky, mir

The Homepage of conky(and almost every definition for conky) state that

> Conky is a free, light-weight system monitor for **X**, that displays any information on your desktop.

So does conky work on Mir?

I was thinking about trying out Mir, but I need conky to work, so I asked this question.

Comment: Why are you worried about Mir, its still not on Ubuntu yet and won't be there until at least 14.10?

Comment: @Jobin I could do some testing.